# Browser removes HttpOnly flag on token cookie set by server

Tags: rest, cookies, spring-security, httponly, cookie-httponly

I have a REST service providing JSON data to a JS application. During authentication, the server sets an HttpOnly cookie named token= and sets the HttpOnly flag. The HttpOnly flag is visible in the browser's developer tools.

But, when the JS app sends the next request (say GET) to the REST server, I see the token attached but I do not see a HttpOnly flag being set by the browser. Is this expected behavior? I looked through some documentation but could not find concrete indications that this is to be expected. I am expecting the browser to retain the HttpOnly flag ON configuration.

On the server side when I call cookies.isHttpOnly(), I get false. Shouldn't this be true given that I had set that token with the same.

Below are my observations:

HTTP Response Header received from REST service:

Header Name: SET-COOKIE

Content:
token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxIiwicm9sZXMiOiJBRE1JTixVU0VSIiwiZXhwIjoxNTEyMzQ1MTM.LqBlD4pdbi9mHH1CWw52US77oefZjo40e7T02lTp7oEaMGslY71INB9WwuhETiQ;Max-Age=2592000;Expires=Sun, 03-Dec-2017 23:52:16 GMT;Path=/;HttpOnly

HTTP Request Header sent by client to REST service:

Header Name: Cookie

Content:
token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiIxIiwicm9sZXMiOiJBRE1JTixVU0VSIiwiZXhwIjoxNTEyMzQ1MTM.LqBlD4pdbi9mHH1CWw52US77oefZjo40e7T02lTp7oEaMGslY71INB9WwuhETiQ